# Adding headers and footers while printing HTML files out of Microsoft Word

Tags: html, css, printing, ms-word

I was given a task of adding headers and footers to printable HTML files.
To be more clear : 
I wish to be able to view the content of those files in Microsoft Word and to have a header and a footer displayed at each Word page. Hopefully, different headers and footers to each page.
Later on the pages would be printed, of course.

I do able to add headers and footers to a regular html document, simply by using commands as :

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

After I defined a "footer" div tag in the html code with some text lines in it.

But it seems that when I open the file as a Word document those text lines would not go to the bottom of the current page.
How would it be possible to place those lines at the top / bottom of the Word page ? Of each page, actually, since I have several pages in the document.

Comment: Do you want the headers and footers to be from the HTML itself, or added in Word? Word lets you add them (I believe) under the Insert menu/tab, which would print with the rest of the document.

Comment: From the HTML itself.
I found a way to place different headers and footers on each page, using the command "page-break-after:always" to decide when a page ends and wrapping each of those "pages" within its own div.
Like this I was able to create some sort of partition and placed headers and footers on the page normally.
The problem is that when I view that in Word, it turns into a regular text, with no headers, footers or page breaks.